# What is the steps of classification of imbalanced dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I need some help from anyone who is familiar with the problem I am facing.

I want to do a classification using SVM, Random Forest and Deep Neural Network(DNN) with two different datasets. One of my datasets is balanced and another one data is highly imbalanced. Below is the image of my dataset which is imbalanced for classification.

[image: Image of imbalanced class dataset]

I want to compare the results of the classification for all machine learning used for both data. Which dataset is producing better results for classification. For balanced dataset, I've got no problem cause the way to handle it normally but for imbalanced I am a little bit confused.

My problem is that I am confused about what is the steps for doing the classification using the imbalanced data. From what I know is that to handle the imbalanced data, we should do sampling.

Do I have to classify first and get the results or should I do the oversampling first and classify and get the results? What are the proper steps in doing the classification with the imbalanced dataset? I hope anyone can help me with this because I am still new in this area.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report


data=pd.read_csv("ImbalancedData.csv")


y = data.Class
x = data.drop('Class,axis=1)


x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site for this, and I imagine they probably already have questions + answers about how to deal with imbalanced data for classification

Comment: How many samples in your 1 class? Such huge class imbalance is common in anomaly detection, which have some techniques for dealing about it. Like formulating it as a one-class problem (training only models class 0), then validate/test on both

Comment: @jonnor For class 0 there are 126,348 samples and class 1 is 1,840 samples.

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the comments, I also think this question is not really suited for SO. But, still to help you, you have a few options:
1) you can take care of imbalance of the data - undersampling the majority class, upsample the minority class etc. You can check SMOTE.

2) for your train and test split, it's important to keep the distribution same between train and test in order to get good results that reflect the real data. Scikit-learn has StrattifySplit that lets you do that instead of regular train_test_split.

3) you can use specific models that are known to he working well with imbalanced data and solve it as if it's an anomaly detection problem. Check out Isolation Forests, Local Outlier Factor, Autoencoders (unsupervised) etc. that can give you better results. Keep in mind that there are many others and hyperparameters to tune.